# JQuery .change triggered on page load for dynamically created options

Tags: jquery, onchange, selectize.js

I am trying to add JQuery change event handler to a select, but the problem is that it is also triggered on page load several times (equal to number of options). The options are set dynamically from database.

The html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="sandbox">
          <select id="fct_address_country_id" class="form-control input-sm">
          <select>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#fct_address_country_id').change(onclick_fct_address_country_id);
    populateSelect2_singleItemPredefined ('fct_address_country_id','select id, name from countries where id = 1 or id = 2');
});

var onclick_fct_address_country_id = function() {
    alert ('edgar');
};

var populateSelect2_singleItemPredefined = function(id, sql_query_str, onChangeHandler){
    sqlQueryJSON_result(sql_query_str).done (function(obj)
    {
        $(document.getElementById(id)).selectize({persist: false,
                                                  maxOptions: 6});
        var selectize_tags = $(document.getElementById(id))[0].selectize;
        selectize_tags.addOption({
                value: '',
                text: 'Select value'
            });
        for (var i = 0; i< obj.length; i++)
        {
            selectize_tags.addOption({
                value: obj[i][0],
                text: obj[i][1]
            });
            selectize_tags.addItem(obj[i][0]);
        }
    });
}
```

I've crashed my mind over this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230952/change-event-fires-multiple-times) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204647/jquery-change-event-firing-on-page-load) does not seem to replicate my case.